# How to AirPlay or stream video to PlayStation 3 from OS X?

Tags: video, display, airplay, streaming

I'm hitting brick walls it seems on finding any topics that pertain to streaming video and / or live display to a PlayStation 3.  I am not sure if I'm just missing the correct terminology or if a solution simply doesn't exist.

My primary goal is to be able to stream videos to a PlayStation 3 similar to how [Beamer](http://beamer-app.com) works.  A bonus would be to stream AirPlay. Are there any solutions for such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Just came looking to see if I could use Airplay, as it would be very convenient to be able to stream from any of my devices.

However, I have been using [medialink](http://www.nullriver.com/products/medialink) for years, using my mac mini as a media server.  It had some troubles when it first came out, but in recent years I've found it extremely reliable, quality is excellent for all definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Using airplay to stream music to your ps3 is not possible because airplay is a function that is only available on apple devices.

If you want to stream music to your os3, you will need a media server on your mac.

Most of the times I use vuse to stream my media to my ps3/4 or smart tv.

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately Vuze has not worked for my situation.  The primary issue is that the PS3 simply will not show up in Vuze and vice versa. Doesn't seem to be a firewall issue either, so I'm not sure what actually prevents it from being seen either way.

Comment: After a quick google search i came to this site: http://serviio.org, perhaps that is wat you need

Comment: funny thing is is that I tried that one and it just simply hung.  Never could get it to work.  I've tried Plex as well with not much success.  Really hoped to get something a little more along the lines of `Beamer` as noted initially.

Comment: There are many non-Apple devices that can *receive* AirPlay signals.

Comment: just get an old apple tv 2, you won't look back. makes streaming music and video a breeze from your iOS devices and from your MacOS. it is the best device i've bought in the past 2-3 years (we had 2 iOS devices and 1 Macbook at home).